# Unable to make mSuperdrive and mBeam API Calls in the Postman Collection

Tags: javascript, edgeengine, edgesdk

I am trying to make mSuperdrive and mBeam API Calls as in the Smart-car-use case ( [ Group C – Car 1] in the postman Collection). When I made the **[C1] → mSuperdrive LOCAL DISCOVERY** api call (to see the Link Local clustering) I can find both of my devices in the response object, but along with the response I am getting the following error.

[image]

And the same error shows when i try to make **[C2]  → mSuperdrive mimik add a media Obj locally (Car 1)** api call also.

[image]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

Please run [B8-1] in postman collection and look for mBeam-v1 microservice in the response. it should look something like below:

```
{
"clientId": "79279c04-8945-4141-8b52-2cb92b78cf43",
            "created": 1616192573759,
            "env": {
                "AUTHORIZATION_KEY": "a98ae340-67b3-11ea-a379-2d7670465870",
                "BEAM": "http://localhost:8083/18f261e8-5af0-4c2c-8b8d-b52e1ff82754/mbeam/v1",
                "MCM.BASE_API_PATH": "/79279c04-8945-4141-8b52-2cb92b78cf43/mbeam/v1",
                "MCM.DB_ENCRYPTION_SUPPORT": "false",
                "MCM.WEBSOCKET_SUPPORT": "true",
                "MPO": "https://mpo.mimik360.com/mPO/v1",
                "SystemSecurityPubKey": "a98ae340-67b3-11ea-a379-2d7670465870",
                "UserId": "2650110035968233472",
                "ownerCode": "1234",
                "signatureKey": "123",
                "uMDS": "http://127.0.0.1:8083/mds/v1"
            },
            "id": "79279c04-8945-4141-8b52-2cb92b78cf43-mbeam-v1",
            "image": "mbeam-v1",
            "imageId": "79279c04-8945-4141-8b52-2cb92b78cf43-mbeam-v1",
            "name": "mbeam-v1",
            "state": "started"

}
```

Please copy the value for "clientId". After you have copied the value go to [B6-1] and open the body of the call. At the very bottom you should see a key titled "BEAM" with a URL. it should look like below:

```
"BEAM":"http://localhost:8083/79279c04-8945-4141-8b52-2cb92b78cf43/mbeam/v1"
```

Update the URL to use the clientId that you copied earlier. ex:

```
"http://localhost:8083/YOUR-mBEAM-CLIENTID-GOES-HERE/mbeam/v1"
```

after its updated hit Send on [B6-1] call and then return to [C2] call and continue.